# Confusion about position: fixed

Tags: html, css

As mentioned in the picture, I want the 'menu' to be fixed on the left side (A fixed Sidebar). To achieve this I tried `position: fixed; top: value;` simply . And the catch is the menu gets fixed but it overlaps the footer and **z-index** property also doesn't seem to work here. Any explanations for this behaivour of the code? And also I'm using bootstrap v4 grid system.

[image]

Comment: Paste code please

Comment: Why can't you just add a bottom distance on your fixed menu that's the same height as the footer? If you provided code, then I didn't have to ask this obvious question.

Comment: I know a glimpse of the code would be suffice for this problem. but I'm actually implementing this on servlet where the forementioned issue occurs and it would be a little hectic to provide the servlet code. works fine in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be perfectly done using `CSS grid`. Clean, modern, semantic and fast.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1.6 consolas;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "navbar navbar navbar" "menu main cart" "footer footer footer";
}

#navbar {
  grid-area: navbar;
}

#sidenav-menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  width: 100px;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sidenav-cart {
  grid-area: cart;
  width: 100px;
}

footer#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav id="navbar">navbar</nav>
  <nav id="sidenav-menu">menu</nav>
  <main role="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </main>
  <div id="sidenav-cart">cart</div>
  <footer id="footer">footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `position: fixed` the element is taken out of the document flow and the top, left, right, bottom properties are applied relative to the viewport.

Using `position: fixed` for a sidebar may or may not be suitable, it depends on how you want that sidebar to behave.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link-collapse').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav-link-collapse').not(this).removeClass('nav-link-show');
    $(this).toggleClass('nav-link-show');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding-top: 4.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.nav-link-collapse:after {
  float: right;
  content: '\f067';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.nav-link-show:after {
  float: right;
  content: '\f068';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.nav-item ul.nav-second-level {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.nav-item ul.nav-second-level > .nav-item {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .sidenav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 230px;
    height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    background: #343a40;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  .navbar-expand-lg .sidenav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .content-wrapper {
    margin-left: 230px;
  }

  .footer {
    width: calc(100% - 230px);
    margin-left: 230px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sidebar Nav</a>
  <button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarCollapse"
    aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sidenav" id="navAccordion">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a
          class="nav-link nav-link-collapse"
          href="#"
          id="hasSubItems"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseSubItems2"
          aria-controls="collapseSubItems2"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >Item 2</a>
        <ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseSubItems2" data-parent="#navAccordion">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="nav-link-text">Item 2.1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="nav-link-text">Item 2.2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a
          class="nav-link nav-link-collapse"
          href="#"
          id="hasSubItems"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#collapseSubItems4"
          aria-controls="collapseSubItems4"
          aria-expanded="false"
        >Item 4</a>
        <ul class="nav-second-level collapse" id="collapseSubItems4" data-parent="#navAccordion">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              <span class="nav-link-text">Item 4.2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline ml-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
    <h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1><h1>Main Content</h1>
  </div>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
          <span>Coded by <a href="https://si-dev.com/ru">SI-Dev</a>, 2018</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

You need to check with the full screen.

Comment: @JustCurious did not any specific requirement and he/she also tried with bootstrap. So I think it was not valid downvote -Rickard Elimaa